# Katalon Script: Find element by attributes and click it

Tags: katalon-studio

I have some yes/no radio buttons and it would be much faster if I did not have to register these as 'test objects' using many clicks in the UI.

Is there a way to edit my test script to find these elements by-attribute and click them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the UI (By that I presume you mean the Object Repository).

For example, if you have the following HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" value="On"> On<br>
  <input type="radio" value="Off"> Off<br>
</form>
```

You can make a parametrized object in the script (and not using web spy/record feature):

```
def switch = ['on', 'off']
TestObject button = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'input[value="'+switch+'"]')
```

You will need to import these:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you and I am excited to try this.  Is there any documentation on how to do things like this?  I am not thrilled at documentation I have found, it seems to encourage heavy use of the Object Repository UI to identify and catalog test objects.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read [this](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Creation+of+Test+Object+in+Object+Repository+in+Runtime) and especially [this discussion](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/5852/using-waitforelementpresent-without-an-object/p1) on creating test objects in script vs using the object repository.

Comment: Thank you.  I got it to work as I wanted by combining the info from your answer and the linked discussions.  I really feel like this is not the intended usage for the product... and at least where my needs are concerned, that's a shame. :)