# Creating objects Katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I have 10 different input buttons (radio) that I want to test.  I want to switch them on and off and test the results on the page.

I want to put the ids for the buttons into EXCEL.  Read the ids (using a loop) and click the buttons.

As far as I can tell to do this Katalon I'll need to create test object and assign them the relevant ids and then click them.

I can do the loop, the EXCEL variables and the click but I can't create the objects and find them on the page.  The bit of code is:

```
TestObject objecToUse = new TestObject("objectName")

objecToUse.setSelectorMethod(SelectorMethod.BASIC)

objecToUse.addProperty("id", ConditionType.EQUALS,"jform_params_show_end_time0")
WebUI.click(objecToUse)
```

The console output just says no such property value for calss: Script....

I could do it by having lots of code - the same for each button but I'm hoping I don't need to do that.

**Update with more code and HTML**

HTML code showing two of the boxes.  I actually search for the for="jform_params_show_end_time0" attribute rather than id.  Also you check whether the button has been pressed via the class - whether it is active or not

```
attributeNo = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('object_path /adminEventsShowEndTimeNo'), 
    'class')

System.out.println(attributeNo)


if (attributeNo.contains('active')) {
    System.out.println('active found in No')

    WebUI.click(findTestObject(value))
}
```

anyway the html is

```
<fieldset id="jform_params_show_end_time" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno radio">
    <input type="radio" id="jform_params_show_end_time0" name="jform[params][show_end_time]" value="0" checked="checked">
    <label for="jform_params_show_end_time0" class="btn active btn-danger">NO </label>

    <input type="radio" id="jform_params_show_end_time1" name="jform[params][show_end_time]" value="1">
    <label  for="jform_params_show_end_time1" class="btn">YES </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="jform_params_show_end_time" class="btn-group btn-group-yesno radio">
    <input type="radio" id="jform_params_show_end_time0" name="jform[params][show_end_time]" value="0" checked="checked">
    <label for="jform_params_show_end_time0" class="btn active btn-danger">NO</label>

    <input type="radio" id="jform_params_show_end_time1" name="jform[params][show_end_time]" value="1"> 
    <label for="jform_params_show_end_time1" class="btn">YES</label>
</fieldset>
```

and I tried

```
TestObject objecToUse = new TestObject("objectName")

objecToUse.setSelectorMethod(SelectorMethod.BASIC)

objecToUse.addProperty("for", ConditionType.EQUALS,"jform_params_show_end_time0")

WebUI.click(objecToUse)
```

which crashes ( my intention is to swap jform_params_show_end_time0 for a variable pulled from the excel spreadsheet)

Comment: Your idea should work fine, but to check what is really happening, you should post the HTML of the page (at least the relevant part) so we can check the id and whole of the error message.

Comment: I've added the HTML and some code fragaments

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302079/katalon-script-find-element-by-attributes-and-click-it/52307770#52307770